# How to increase and decrease a text value with two buttons

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css

I'm trying to increase a text value using two buttons, one on each side of the text, which either increase the value by 10 or decrease it by 10, and the value can't go under 10km or over 90km.

Here is the app screen so you can see what I mean:

[image]

Update: I've now been given code to work with but it doesn't have the "km" value after the number so it goes 10,20,30 instead of 10km, 20km, 30km. Does anyone know how to adjust this code to do what I want?

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#increment").click(function(){
if($('#number').val() !="90"){
var $n = $("#number");
$n.val(Number($n.val())+10);
}
}); 

$("#decrement").click(function(){
if($('#number').val() !="10"){
var $n = $("#number");
$n.val(Number($n.val())-10);
    }
});

});
</script>
</head>
<style>
.Radius{
font-size:14px;
font-family:"gillsans";
color: #4361AD;  
text-align: center;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="Maincontainer">
<input type="text" value="10" id="number" class="Radius" style="background-color:transparent; border:0px solid white; width:110px;     margin-left:15px;"/>
<input type="button" id="increment" value="Increment"/>
<input type="button" id="decrement" value="decrement"/>
</div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/deepanv29/4b7adopb/

Comment: Could you share any code you have at the moment?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Any efforts so far? Or it's just another "write code for me, please" request?

Comment: do you want to only change the value to zoom in zoom out the map aslo based on value

Comment: sorry no code, I'm still learning. I can only do really basic stuff on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
<body>
  <input type="text" value="10Km" id="number"/>
  <input type="hidden" value="10" id="number1"/>
  <input type="button" id="increment" value="Increment"/>
  <input type="button" id="decrement" value="decrement"/>
</body>
</div>

<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#increment").click(function(){
      if($('#number1').val() !="90"){
        var $n = $("#number1");
        $n.val(Number($n.val())+10);
        var value = $n.val();
        $("#number").val(value +'Km');
       }
    }); 

    $("#decrement").click(function(){
      if($('#number1').val() !="10"){
        var $n = $("#number1");
        $n.val(Number($n.val())-10);
        var value = $n.val();
        $("#number").val(value +'Km');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[updates Js fiddle demo for the above code](https://jsfiddle.net/deepanv29/4b7adopb/6/)

Comment: Thanks bud, I see it works in jsfiddle but when I paste it with the javascript in <script></script> tags directly underneath the input tags it doesn't work. Is this were the script tags are supposed to go? I feel like a complete novice asking these questions.

Comment: also add related jquery files in the head tag.you can add script tag just above the ending  body tag. That should be fine.

Comment: I've updated my main post but I think you answered my question. I have no jquery files, when you say related what do you mean by that?

Comment: i have updated my code check it out in the head tag i have added a line you have to add it in your head tag too. these files are added to define $ or jQuery we type in the code. i not good at explaining so this is the best i can give you.

Comment: You Are The Man. Thankyou so much, now all I need to do is make it look pretty. Hopefully it's not too long till I can code things like this myself :).

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> works fine, the updated code didn't.

Comment: Its good that the code helped you.Sure you code like this soon .have a good time buddy.

Comment: oh i will change it then.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that the text value doesn't have "km" in it, is there a way to adjust the code so it has km after the number values, so 10km, 20km, 30km etc? I tried but failed.

Comment: Hi marcus i have updated the js fiddle code and the code above .check the changes it is working. i was caught up in another work thats why i am updating so late.

Comment: Thanks a lot *again*. You're not late at all :).

Answer (score 1):

you just need to increment and decrement the value at button click.

```
int value = 10;

protected void BtnIncre_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (value < 90) 
    {
        value += 10;
        Session["Value"] = value;
    }
} 

protected void BtnDecre_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (value > 10)
    {
        value -= 10;
        Session["Value"] = value;
     }
}
```

Comment: code should be if(value<=80){  instead of  if(value<=90){  "this way upper limit will not cross 90".

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex and Rufus, I'll see if I can get this to work. May run into trouble linking this to the buttons themselves...but I'll let you know how I go.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="dec" value="DEC" onclick="dec();">
    <input type="text" id="Number_value" value="0" readonly>
    <input type="button" id="inc" value="INC" onclick="inc();">
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
        function inc()
        {
            var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number_value').value);  
            val+=10;
            if(val>90) val = 90;
            document.getElementById('Number_value').value = val;
        }
        function dec()
        {
            var val = parseInt(document.getElementById('Number_value').value);  
            val-=10;
            if(va<10) val = 10;
            document.getElementById('Number_value').value = val;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have even showed me how to make the buttons, thanks bud. I'll see which of the two works best.

Comment: I noticed that this goes above 90 and below 10, is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for the input but I decided to use Deepan Venkatesh code :).